# Combinatorics question, grouping of 62 people broken into 3 subgroups, going to different restaurants

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

I am trying to understand whether it is possible to group 62 people into 3 groups with some requirements:

Group A is 10 people

Group B 26

Group C 26

Every day 62 people will go out for dinner. But it will be in these 3 different groups. And they will go to different restaurants.
These groups will go to dinner 6 times in total, and there is a list of 6 different restaurants any group can choose to go to.

The requirements, and I would like to see whether this is possible are as follows:

1. Can we ensure that 60 people (out of the whole 62) will join group A for dinner at least once? I am aware that this would mean that it must be 10 completely different people each night on that group.
2. Also ensure that everyone can visit all 6 restaurants?
3. Ensure that groups do not repeat? (If even one person is different in a group, then that's fine)

Comment: "Can we ensure that $60$ people will join group A for dinner at least once?" - No, there are only $52$ people outside of group A!!!

Comment: "Can we ensure that everyone will visit all $6$ restaurants over the two weeks?" - No, because that would require $18$ dinners in total, and you have allowed only $6$ dinners in total. Also - what (on earth) do those "two weeks" have to do with anything in this question???

Comment: The two comments above are basically just to imply to you that your question is a complete mess, and as such, it cannot be answered in a proper conceivable manner.

Comment: @barakmanos You are right about the 2 weeks, my mistake. I removed it from my question. However the rest of the information is correct. I didn't understand your first point, so if you think that it isn't possible, can you then please write an answer with an explanation as to why?

Comment: No, because it is too obvious. Something in your question is simply not depicted correctly IMO. How can $60$ people join group A when there are only $52$ people outside this group?????

Comment: We are talking about 60 people, out of the 62 in total being a part of group A, over a course of 6 dinners. So I realize that it must be 10 completely different people every night. But this was stated in the question.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. Including group A, a dinner can consist of $10$ people, $36$ people or $62$ people. What's the point in mentioning "$60$" here???

Comment: Are you sure that it's not simply - every person gets $6$ dinners, and **doesn't** have to attend a dinner with his fellow group-mates?

Comment: 60 is the requirement. That 60 different people will be part of a group of 10 people. Every day 62 people will go out for dinner. But it will be in 3 different groups. And they will go to different restaurants.

Comment: As I have already mentioned, if people must go to dinner together with their groups, then a dinner including group A can be $10$, $36$ or $62$ people. Hence my notion of your question lacking basic sense in its current format.

Comment: Group A will always be 10 people, I'm not sure how you came up with the other numbers

Comment: $10+26=36$ and $10+26+26=62$.

Comment: Group A consists of 10 people. Group B will consist of 26 people. Same for Group C. All 6 nights it will always be like that. I don't think you have understood the question clearly. And I think we should refrain from writing any more comments here, as we will confuse anyone who visits this question.

Comment: It seems to me that Barak Manos is assuming the groups are fixed, but the question actually requires a different grouping for each day (even though the groups are the same size, members of the group change from day to day)

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando You are correct. I assumed that " I am aware that this would mean that it must be 10 completely different people each night on that group." and requirement #3 would make this clear.